# how to describe this conditional constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The constraint I want to place is M*xi-yi<0,that is to say when yi is equal to 0 ,then xi must equal to 0 .However the constraint is only needed when a>b(a,b are both the parameters)
Can I describe the constraint as below?
M*xi-yi<0,(a>b)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Don't generate these constraints when `a<=b`. This is usually done with some kind of `if` (depending on the language and modeling tools being used).